# Writing an atoi to convert string to integer

Tags: c++, c++11

I am writing an atoi to convert string to integer. Here is my code of atoi()function

```
int atoi(string str) {
    int num=0;
    int sign=1;
    int len=str.size();    
    int i=0;
    if(str[i]==' '&& i<len) i++;
    if(str[i]=='+') i++;
    if(str[i]=='-') {i++;sign=-1;}

    for(;i<len;i++){
        if(str[i]==' ') break;
        if(str[i]<'0' || str[i]>'9') break;
        if(INT_MAX/10<num || INT_MAX/10==num && INT_MAX%10<(str[i]-'0'))
        { return sign==-1 ?INT_MIN:INT_MAX;
        break;
        }
        num=num*10+str[i]-'0';
    }
    return num*sign;

    }
```

However, when input '1', output is 0, Why is that please?

Comment: Have you tried to debug your code with `gdb`?

Comment: I think his question is valid...he showed the code he tried and the testing performed to narrow down the problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

well the code is kind of buggy:

- this `if(str[i]<'0' || str[i]>'9') break;` won't get you very far; if you input `12aaa` you want your method to return some error code or nothing, not the integer part of the string.
- I don't even know what this is supposed to be....

  ```
      if(INT_MAX/10<num || INT_MAX/10==num && INT_MAX%10<(str[i]-'0'))
      { return sign==-1 ?INT_MIN:INT_MAX;
      break;
      }
  ```
- Get rid of the last if statement I highlighted, correct the first one so that the code does not try to convert anything other than valid integer strings, and the code should work.